# Как удалить папку под контролем svn?

Tags: svn, tortoise-svn

Создал папочку, тыкнул SVN checkout, связал с репозиторием. Но не с тем. Как отцепить ее? Удалить и пересоздать тоже не могу, потому что там внутри невидимая папка .svn и в ней занят файл. svn remove не помогает. Сообщает is the root of a working copy and cannot be deleted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Перезапустите TortoiseSVN, чтобы файл перестал быть занят. После этого удаляйте папку.